# Animated horse movie/series 1980s-early 1990s, hunted by mad scientist with robot dog

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

Looking to identify an animated movie I saw in the US in about 1995 probably on VHS (or less likely perhaps an episode of a TV series of which I have never seen another episode).

**Plot:**

Features horses who live in the wild and are hunted by a mad scientist in a mountain lair. He hates horses and plans turn them into dog food. The horses have to evade his traps and I think at the end they foil his plans.

Particular elements that may be useful in finding this film:

- Animated, color, animation style seemed American
- I likely rented it in about 1995 on VHS. Video store had lots of 1980's era animated movies so could be from that era
- Vividly remember a few key elements:

  1. There are two remote-controlled grey robot dogs (think: bulldog). One is small and is like a pet to the mad scientist. One is huge and scoops up the trapped horses in his mouth to bring them back to the lair (maybe 10 at a time).
  2. The horses are trapped variously in nets and pits
  3. The scientist wears a lab coat and is short and stout. He may be a child. I think he had a bad experience
  4. Inside of the mountain lair contains a machine he plans to use to turn the horses into dog food. I think the horses are freed from a giant holding net inside the mountain before he can use it.

Other points that may help:

- Early on the horses are trying to figure out why their friends are disappearing
- Horses seem to live in a forest habitat
- Horses are various different colors, but I believe all natural
- I do not remember any names, or if the horses were referred to as horses, ponies, brumbies, mustangs etc.

Comment: Wow, I really want to say that you are just fever dreaming a mixed up version of "The Last Unicorn" because there are some superficial similarities (monster scooping up horses in particular) but I'm sure that's not it.

Answer (score 2):

It could be *The Silver Brumby* (original release: 29 October 1994 – 17 September 1998).

> The series focuses on Thowra, a silver colt, his brothers Storm and Arrow and their friends the bush animals in their continued quest to resist the Men's efforts to capture them.
>
> Source: Wikipedia article for [*The Silver Brumby*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silver_Brumby)

Comment: I am very convinced about the plot of the mad scientist and robot dogs, which as far as I have seen was never a Silver Brumby episode and outside of its setting.

Comment: Oh, ok. It was a long shot any way.

Comment: Yes. It's the music I was definitely looking for. The first part of the song reminds me of RAF - Self Control,